# ManyToOne relation connect via embbeded fielld

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

jpa/spring-data question

i have class Plant which has embbededId PlantId
and i have class Image which as Embbeded field PlantId

this means each image connect to a plant. so the connection is one to many (one plant many image)

i tried something like that(which doesnt work)

```
@entity
public class Plant{
     @EmbbededId
     PlantId id
}

@entity
public class Image{
     @Id
     Long id

     @Embbeded
     PlantId plantId

     @ManyToOne
     Plant plant

}
```

how can i fix the code to get the result i'm looking for?
thanks

Oak

EDIT:
How can i map the columns for the ManyToOne relation if i have composite id for Plant?

Comment: I don't understand why you are putting the plantId in the Image when you can just call image.getPlant().getId().  You only need Image to have its own ID and a relationship to plant.  If plant's ID is composite, you'll need to map the join columns so JPA knows what fields to use in the Image table as foreign keys.

Comment: hey! idont have to put plantId in image. plantId is composite from 4 longs. i just dont know how to map the columns of the plantId so JPA will know how to connect the @ManyToOne relation.

Comment: Make your life simpler and your app faster: use single-column autogenerated IDs.

Comment: hey @JB Nizet, in this case it will be easier to do composite. other wise i'll have to split the key each time to work with it. but i'll do it if i don't have other choice

Comment: How could you split a single-column primary key?

Comment: what i mean  that if i change it to a single-column primary key i would have to combine info of 4 longs into 1. so each time i fetch the table i would have to split the data from that long var

Comment: Why would you need 4 longs to identify something uniquely? Just one is largely sufficient. Make all your entities use single-column primary keys, and everything will be much easier, and much cleaner.

Comment: because each one of the long hold different data. so i should choose whatever to merge them to one big long which will make data less readble and force me to break this long many to 4 parts. the 2nd option is to set multi-columns primary key. after some checking i dont realy need them to be long .small int for most of them will be enough. why you against multi-columns primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing once you remove the plantId embeddable is the join column definitions on the ManyToOne mapping so that JPA knows what foreign keys to use to match up to the id fields in Plant.  Something like:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="FK_1", referencedColumnName="PK1"),
        @JoinColumn(name="FK_2", referencedColumnName="PK2"),
        @JoinColumn(name="FK_3", referencedColumnName="PK3") 
        })
Plant plant;
```